# Audio and Speech in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking to better understand the audio capabilities (if any) in Gazebo. From the [Wishlist](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Wishlist), it sounds like Gazebo does not currently have the ability to hear any input from the world and respond to it (a la speech recognition). Is this correct? Additionally, does Gazebo allow the simulated robot to play sounds, or do any form of speech synthesis?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1328/audio-and-speech-in-gazebo/) by [crypticstar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/204/crypticstar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-02-13**:
Speech synthesis/sounds for what audience? E.g are you referring to speech/sounds that another simulated robot can hear? Or are you referring to sounds that a human at a computer somewhere can hear (that's generated by a robot in gazebo)?

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2013-08-04**:
That would be great, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is an OpenAL branch in Gazebo that implements this feature. It will be distributed in gazebo-1.10.0

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/aa5cc749fc6831bd367bf0455a3fac06b50e8fbe/?at=openal

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0